# CSS coding issue with my logo and inline block nav not lining up

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS but loving it so far. But, I've hit a road block with my code. I'm almost there but need some proper guidance.

I have provided my website where I'm attempting to place my logo to the left side of my nav. I want the site content CENTERED with a width of 960px and 0px from the top (against the top of the browser). I am using the CSS `display: inline` with `li` selectors to try to achieve my goal.

I'm trying to also get the inline nav to be right up against the logo. I'm also trying to mimic the logo's top 4px border with the CSS `a:hover` selector on the nav. I want this to be at the `margin-top: 0px` in the browser.

Here's the link to my almost correct logo/nav layout:

http://multimediaxchange.com/vls/index.php?page=home

**Here's my CSS CODE:**

```
.topbar {
    width:960px;
    height:87px;
    text-align:center;
}

.topbar-inner {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.logo {
    margin-top:0px;
    display:inline;
}

img {
    float:left;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu {
    display:inline;
    margin-top:0px;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-top:4px solid #FFF;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-top:40px;
    min-width:80px;
}

.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.menu li a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover {
    border-top-color: #039;
}

.menu li:hover a {
    color:#039;
}

body { 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.content { 
    height:500px; 
    padding:0px 20px 20px 20px; 
    text-align:left; 
    font-size:12px; 
}

.footer { 
    border-top:1px solid #DFDFDF; 
    width:960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-size:11px; 
    text-align:center; 
}
```

**Here's the HTML Code:**

```
<?php
// Load Setup document:
include('_config/setup.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-inner">
            <div class="logo"><img src="/vls/_images/mylogo.png" height="87" width="287"/></div>
            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="menu"><?php include('_template/nav_main.php'); ?></div>
            <!-- menu -->
        </div>
        <!-- topbar-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- topbar -->
    <div class="bdy_hdr"><?php get_page_name($dbc, $pg); ?></div>                    
    <div class="content"><?php get_page_body($dbc, $pg); ?></div>
    <div class="footer"><?php include('_template/footer.php'); ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aaron, welcome to SO.

Comment: thank you steve! almost there, how can I get it to the very top 0px of the browser, and I do want it right up against the logo so that when you hover the blue 4px border appears to continue along the top "seamless" so to speak..? :)

Comment: Yep you're off to a good start with obvious effort and good formatting :)  If an answer here helps you, community loves upvotes, and if an answer solves your problem, please mark it "accepted".  Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secrets are in the `.topbar` class.  Remove the `text-align:center`, and instead add a `margin:0 auto`.  Should look like this:

```
.topbar {
    width:960px;
    height:87px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

The `text-align:center` prevents the `<ul>` from being centered in the remaining space after the image floats, so the top border looks seamless.

The `margin:0 auto` centers the whole kaboodle.

---

Add this line:

```
.menu ul {
    margin:0;
}
```

and it will be on the top of the browser.  My comments about a lot of extra junk still apply though :)

---

**EDIT**

Here's your page, with the "minimalist" markup and styling I'm talking about.  There's one or two minor tricks a beginner may not know, but you should easily understand pretty much everything.

Just slice out all the crap extra divs, basically, and you can chase down problems quicker, target elements easier, have a lighter page (in bytes, that is) and generally add a bit of elegance to your solutions.

This rebuild does everything the original did, in half the space.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <img src="logo.png" height="87" width="287"/>
        <ul class='menu'>
            <!-- Not great practice to stagger </li> like this,
                 but a good way to avoid rogue padding. -->
            <li><a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=staffing">Staffing</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=jobs">Jobs</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=training">Training</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=gsa">GSA</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=why_us">Why Us</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=clients">Clients</a>
            </li><li><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    ...the rest of your page...
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}

.topbar {
    width:960px;
    height:87px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.topbar img {
    float:left;
    border: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    margin:0 0 0 287px;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-top:4px solid #FFF;
    list-style:none;
    padding-top:40px;
    min-width:80px;
}

ul.menu li a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
    border-top-color: #039;
}

ul.menu li:hover a {
    color:#039;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it's almost there! I'm starting to understand better how this CSS stuff works. I find myself constantly reading on w3schools, lol :P

Comment: i was able to place the text-align:center in the code as follows to achieve my actual desired look:

Comment: .menu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
    border-top:4px solid #FFF;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-top:40px;
    min-width:80px;
 text-align:center;
}

Comment: my guess is, is it something to do with the img {float:left;} ?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but it was a red herring.  Turns out there's a hidden margin on the `ul` element.

Comment: BTW can't help myself, have to tell you that W3Schools is not that great - they've got good Google ranking but a lot of small flaws.  Maybe OK for baby steps but take them with a grain of salt: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: AWESOME!! thank you! do you mean to go through the css code and take out extra attributes that really don't need to be there?

Comment: Well, I like a minimalist style since it's easier to debug.  There's a bunch of `div`s which are not necessary.  The CSS will have to be updated a little but no biggie.  Since I'm elbow deep anyway, I'll add an example of a cleaner HTML rebuild to my answer, just a sec.

Comment: Oh, also the "minimialist style" is more a good practice thing, the W3Schools problems are a different topic.  Anyway you're welcome, glad to help, happy coding, I've got to go, Gotham needs me.

Comment: ty, I'll keep that in mind :/ BTW, cleaned up, and tightened up my CSS... much lighter :)

Answer (score 3):

everything is right but you need to add this property margin:0 auto; not to the topbar-inner class but to the topbar class, and this like like this. so change present

```
.topbar {
    width:960px;
    height:87px;
text-align:center;
}
```

to

```
.topbar {
    width:960px;
    height:87px;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to put your `divs` inside a container, something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-inner">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/vls/_images/mylogo.png" height="87" width="287"/>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <?php include('_template/nav_main.php'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bdy_hdr">
        <?php get_page_name($dbc, $pg); ?>
    </div>                    
    <div class="content">
        <?php get_page_body($dbc, $pg); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <?php include('_template/footer.php'); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then do just this in your CSS:

```
.topbar{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

I suggest you to give a `width` to `.bdy_hdr`, `.content` and `.footer` and then do the same with them, i.e:

```
.bdy_hdr,
.content,
.footer{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```